# Add value and key in NSDictionary from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have two `NSArray`. They are `myArray` & `alphabets`. `myArray` have some value and `alphabets` have the list of all alphabets.

I also have a `NSMutableDictionary` which is called `finalDic`. Where I want to add `myArray` values according to it's first latter where the first latter will be it's key. For doing that I add an extra `NSMutableArray` called `objArray`. Below is my code.

```
myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
               @"Bangladesh",
               @"France",
               @"Italy",
               @"Canada",
               @"Austria",
               @"Germany",
               @"Bolivia",
               @"Argentina",
               @"England", nil];

NSArray *alphabets = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *finalDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *objArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int i;
    int k;

    for (i = 0; i < [alphabets count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *alp = [alphabets objectAtIndex:i];
        for (k = 0; k < [myArray count]; k++)
        {
            NSString *vlu = [myArray objectAtIndex:k];
            if([[myArray objectAtIndex:k] hasPrefix:[alphabets objectAtIndex:i]])
            {
                [objArray addObject:[myArray objectAtIndex:k]];
            }
        }

        if (objArray != nil)
        {
            [finalDic setObject:objArray forKey:[alphabets objectAtIndex:i]];
            [objArray removeAllObjects];
        }
    }
NSLog(@"finalDic %@", finalDic);
```

The problem is I am not getting the accurate result. I am getting this `NSLog` :

```
finalDic {
A =     (
);
B =     (
);
C =     (
);
D =     (
);
E =     (
);
F =     (
);
G =     (
);
H =     (
);
I =     (
);
J =     (
);
K =     (
);
L =     (
);
M =     (
);
N =     (
);
O =     (
);
P =     (
);
Q =     (
);
R =     (
);
S =     (
);
T =     (
);
U =     (
);
V =     (
);
W =     (
);
X =     (
);
Y =     (
);
Z =     (
);
}
```

I debug the code and seen that after adding first `key` and it's value (which is `objArray`) the first `key` and `value` getting empty!, just before beginning 2nd `for loop` for `B`. Don't know why? Am I missing something?

Please reply if you understand my problem. A lot of thanks in advance.

Comment: You are executing `[objArray removeAllObjects];` every loop iteration.  What other result would you expect?  Your bug is reusing `objArray`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I used it, because otherwise it will added all values for every single key. So, I want to make it empty. I also used objArray = nill; But it's not working. Do you have any suggestion on it?

Comment: I already told you: you're reusing `objArray`.  Don't do that.

Comment: Got it. I have to `alloc` & `init` it just after 1st `for loop` and there is an another correction, which is, I have to check the `objArray` with it's value ([objArray count] != nill), not like `objArray != nill`. Thanks. It's perfectly working. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you step through it you will see that your finalDic is good until [objArray removeAllObjects];

FinalDic is pointing to objArray. You need to write create a temporary object or write this differently.